# Pointer to an array of pointers to nodes

Tags: c, pointers, struct, nodes

With this struct

```
typedef struct tNode_t {
    struct tNode_t **a;
} tNode;
```

I want to be able to have `a` point to an array to 5 pointers to tNodes

example main:

```
int main()
{
    tNode t;
    tNode (*alpha)[5];
    t.a = alpha;
}
```

why doesn't this work?

Comment: And what does compiler say to you? ;-) Are you sure you declared alpha correctly as you wished?

Comment: Why not just build the array into the struct? If you know the length is always `5`:  `struct tNode_t { struct tNode_t *a[5]; }`

Comment: @Kylo it doesn't compile and says ` warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type`

Comment: @Lee for the assignment we can't do that in the struct, it has to be pointing to an array of pointers to nodes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This defines a pointer to an array of tNodes:

```
tNode (*alpha)[5];
```

This defines an array of pointers to tNodes:

```
tNode *alpha[5];
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code `alpha` and `a` are pointers to very different objects. And since both are pointers, as you correctly defined them, **no decaying will take place**. Only arrays decay so `alpha` can't simply decay to another pointer type.

And why are they so different ? When you increment a, it will point to the next `struct tNode_t *`. When you increment `alpha` it will point 5 `struct tNode *` further.